# Rsync files based on highest alpha within a date

Tags: sync, rsync

I'd like to rsync a folder which contains files in the format

```
fixed string<yyyy-mm-dd><version letter>.xml
```

The version letter is a, b, c, ... and I only want the files with the latest version for each date.  So if there are three files for a given date, I only want the one ending in 'c'.

The files are reasonably big and there are a lot of them, so I need to avoid syncing old versions.

My starting position is this...

```
rsync -az --progress --exclude '.svn' --exclude 'tmp/' --relative site.com::folder/*.* .
```

Any guidance warmly welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly what I was after was a bit beyond what rsync can do on its own.  So instead, I've used it to get a list of files, then process that through R to create the list of files I want and then use rsync to download those files.

**Get Original List of Files**

```
rsync --list-only remoteSite.com::folder/subFolder/*.xml > filelist.txt
```

**Select the ones I want (using R)**

```
  fileList <- read_delim("filelist.txt" ,delim = " ", 
                         col_names = c("permission", "size", "date", "time", "filename")) %>%
    select(-permission) %>%
        mutate(speechdate = substr(filename,8,17),
           version = substr(filename, 18,18)) %>%
    group_by(speechdate) %>%
    arrange(desc(version)) %>%
    # Just get the highest version for each date
    filter(row_number()==1) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    summarise(filename) %>%
    select(filename) %>%
    arrange(filename)

write.table(fileList, "latestFilesForDownload.txt", 
            sep="", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

**Download Files Needed**

```
rsync -az --files-from=latestFilesForDownload.txt remoteSite.com::folder/subFolder/ .
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you could get a list of the files with

```
rsync 'site.com::folder/*.*'
```

Then (I'm assuming the files don't have spaces in their names, adjust if so) you could extract only the filenames with:

```
rsync 'site.com::folder/*.*' | perl -pe's/^.* //;'
```

But if you are doing that, you might as well extract the date/version letter at the same time:

```
rsync 'site.com::folder/*.*' | perl -ne'
  /^.* (.*)(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)(.)?\.xml/;
  $fixed = $1;
  $out{$2} = $3;
  END { foreach (sort keys %out) { print "$fixed$_$out{$_}.xml\n"; } }'
```

That would give you a list of all the files with the latest extensions (assuming rsync returned the files in ascending order; if it doesn't you could sort its output first and then feed into that short script). You could then use rsync's `--files-from` parameter to get it to download only those files.

Comment: Thanks @M Somerville.